# Big loop in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I calculate price by this loop

```
uint tokenPrice = 1e15;
uint tokenPriceStep = 1e11;//
uint sendValue = 3e18; //3 ETH
uint balance = 0;
do {    
    balance += 1e18;
    sendValue -= tokenPrice;
    tokenPrice += tokenPriceStep;
} while (sendValue > tokenPrice);
if(sendValue > 0){
    balance += sendValue *  1e18 / tokenPrice;
    tokenPrice += (sendValue *  1e18 / tokenPrice) * tokenPriceStep / 1e18;
    sendValue = 0;
}
```

But this is cost to much gas. And REMIX just crashed when i run this. What can i must do? I need this loop to calculate price like this:

For example logics looks like this:
First colum is number
Second colum is my value (my money)
Third is my token balance
Forth colum is price (that grow by 1 or any else)

```
0 - 3000.00000 -> 0.00000 -> 100.00000
1 - 2900.00000 -> 1.00000 -> 101.00000
2 - 2799.00000 -> 2.00000 -> 102.00000
3 - 2697.00000 -> 3.00000 -> 103.00000
4 - 2594.00000 -> 4.00000 -> 104.00000
5 - 2490.00000 -> 5.00000 -> 105.00000
6 - 2385.00000 -> 6.00000 -> 106.00000
7 - 2279.00000 -> 7.00000 -> 107.00000
8 - 2172.00000 -> 8.00000 -> 108.00000
9 - 2064.00000 -> 9.00000 -> 109.00000
10 - 1955.00000 -> 10.00000 -> 110.00000
11 - 1845.00000 -> 11.00000 -> 111.00000
12 - 1734.00000 -> 12.00000 -> 112.00000
13 - 1622.00000 -> 13.00000 -> 113.00000
14 - 1509.00000 -> 14.00000 -> 114.00000
15 - 1395.00000 -> 15.00000 -> 115.00000
16 - 1280.00000 -> 16.00000 -> 116.00000
17 - 1164.00000 -> 17.00000 -> 117.00000
18 - 1047.00000 -> 18.00000 -> 118.00000
19 - 929.00000 -> 19.00000 -> 119.00000
20 - 810.00000 -> 20.00000 -> 120.00000
21 - 690.00000 -> 21.00000 -> 121.00000
22 - 569.00000 -> 22.00000 -> 122.00000
23 - 447.00000 -> 23.00000 -> 123.00000
24 - 324.00000 -> 24.00000 -> 124.00000
25 - 200.00000 -> 25.00000 -> 125.00000
26 - 75.00000 -> 26.00000 -> 126.00000
27 - 0.00000 -> 26.59524 -> 126.59524
```

---

Please help, i can't know what to do!

Comment: Can you not just replace the loop with modulus, division, and multiplication? Sounds like you are simply moving towards the remainder

Comment: Maybe, but i don't know how to do this. Can u help me to do this. I just don't understand

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this without a loop:

```
uint times = sendValue / tokenPrice; // this is how many time the loop would run
balance += times * (1e18);
tokenPrice += times * tokePriceStep;
sendValue -= times * tokenPrice;
```

After that the rest is the same.
You should always try to avoid loops in your contract since it is very easy to run out of gas or sometimes even exceed the block's gas limit.

Comment: No, because your calculation does not support rising prices, buying in every single token! Look for example!